# Determine what item was clicked in my ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

How can I determine what item was clicked on my ListBox?

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (yourListBoxName.SelectedIndex!=-1) {
      // do stuff with yourListBoxName.SelectedIndex
    }
```

Without very basic information on what you want to do, this is very basic.